# Destroy PHP session by leaving a browser

Tags: php, session, browser

When you leave a browser, does it destroy the php sessions?

For example I start playing a video when the user visit the site for the first time, but when the user goes back to the first page, the video may not play again.

So that's why I need to know if a session destroy's when the user leaves the browser.

Comment: are you concerned with the user leaving the browser or leaving the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the browser destroys the session cookie that associates the browser with the PHP session.

The PHP session itself will be destroyed when it is inactive for a configurable time period.

Comment: PHP sessions are stored on the server, but how does the server know wich session belongs to wich user? By the IP adress?

Comment: By the id it puts in the session cookie that was mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Logically the session should destroy when you close the browser. But still in some browsers like Firefox, while user saves the open-tabs, browser keeps the sessions.

In addition, closing a tab is not the same as closing the browser and sessions will still remain (won't destory).

Answer (score 0):

Closing the browser destroys the session. Also PHP session itself will be destroyed when it is inactive for a some time period.

Manually you can do this

Put this code at the top of the page where you land when you've successfully logged in:

```
$_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); //your last activity was now, having logged in.
$_SESSION['expire_time'] = 3*60*60;
```

Then you should put this code at the top of every php file

```
if( $_SESSION['last_activity'] < time()-$_SESSION['expire_time'] ) {
    header('Location: logout.php'); 
} else{ 
    $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); //this was the moment of last activity.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A session gets destroyed when someone shuts down his browser.